# How do I update column description in BigQuery table using python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-bigquery

I can use
`SchemaField(f"{field_name}", f"{field_type}", mode="NULLABLE", description=...)` while making a new table.

But I want to update the description of the column of the already uploaded table.

Comment: https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.update_table

Comment: @ZhongDai Isn't that method used to update tables' description? I need a way to update the description of the column of the already uploaded table.

Comment: Hello @RamPatil. If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, please let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, we don’t have such a mechanism available yet to update a column description of the table through the client library. As a workaround, you can try the following available options to update your table column level description:

Option 1: Using the following `ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN SET OPTIONS` data definition language (DDL) statement:

```
ALTER TABLE `projectID.datasetID.tableID`
ALTER COLUMN Name
SET OPTIONS (
 description="Country Name"
);
```

Refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#alter_column_set_options_statement) for more information about the `ALTER COLUMN SET OPTIONS` statement.

Option 2: Using the bq command-line tool's `bq update` command:

Step 1: Get the JSON schema by running the following `bq show` command:

```
bq show --format=prettyjson projectID:datasetID.tableID > table.json
```

Step 2: Then copy the schema from the `table.json` to `schema.json` file.

Note: Don’t copy the entire data from the ‘table.json’ file, copy only the schema, it will look something like below:

```
[
    {
        "description": "Country Name",
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "Name",
        "type": "STRING"
    }
]
```

Step 3: In the ‘schema.json’ file, modify the description name as you like. Then, run the following `bq update` command to update a table column description.

```
bq update projectID:datasetID.tableID schema.json
```

Refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_update) for more information about `bq update` command.

Option 3: Calling the `tables.patch` API method:

Refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/patch) for more information about `tables.patch` API method.

As per your requirement, I took the following Python code from this [medium article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/patch-and-update-table-bigquery-part-iii-7f2547021926) and not from the Google Cloud official docs. So Google Cloud will not provide any support for this code.

Step 1: Add the schema in the ‘schema.py’ file and modify the column description name as per your requirement:

```
#Add field schema
TableObject = {
   "tableReference": {
     "projectId": "projectID",
     "datasetId": "datasetID",
     "tableId": "tableID",
   },
   "schema": {
     "fields": [
         {
           "description": "Country Name",
           "mode": "NULLABLE",
           "name": "Name",
           "type": "STRING"
         }
       ],
   },
}
```

Step 2: Run the following code to get the expected result:

Note: keep that schema.py and following code file in the same directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from schema import TableObject
# [START Table Creator]
def PatchTable(bigquery):
   tables = bigquery.tables()
   tables.patch(                        
         projectId=TableObject['tableReference']['projectId'],\
         datasetId=TableObject['tableReference']['datasetId'],\
         tableId=TableObject['tableReference']['tableId'], \
         body=TableObject).execute()
   print ("Table Patched")
# [END]
def main():
   #To get credentials
   credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
   # Construct the service object for interacting with the BigQuery API.
   bigquery = discovery.build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials)
   PatchTable(bigquery)
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
   print ("BigQuery Table Patch")
```

Comment: 1)While reading documentation, I came across this https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas, but I can't give column data type while creating a table. It is a mandatory field.
2) I am using load_table_from_dataframe() to upload data which makes the dataset if not created but it does not have description from which I can set

Comment: Hello @RamPatil. 1. Alternatively, you can try a schema [auto-detection](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect#auto-detect) when you load data into BigQuery and when you query an external data source.
2. For this question, I don't want to flood too many things on this same thread. So please create this as a new question that helps future Stack Overflow visitors to find a relevant issue and solution quickly.

Answer (score 2):

As of August 2023 (with `google-cloud-bigquery` version 3.10.0) you *can* update column descriptions of a table or view:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()
table = client.get_table("dataset.table")  # <-- replace w/ your dataset/table IDs

# convert Table object to dict (so we can change things)
table_def = table.to_api_repr()  

# change the description of the first column
table_def["schema"]["fields"][0]["description"] = "I'm different!"

# convert the dict back to a Table object
table = table.from_api_repr(table_def)

# call patch with just the values under "schema"
client.update_table(table, ["schema"])
```

All the official Python client does is call `PATCH` on the resource while restricting the data to whatever dict keys specified. Thus if the discovery-based API client can do it then the official client can do it!