# How to change the description of a field nested in a struct via the DDL in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, ddl, alter-table

Let's say I have the following table:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tmp.table_description_test AS (
  SELECT
    1 AS a,
    STRUCT(2 AS c, 3 AS d) AS b
)
```

Adding a description for `a` or `b` is easy:

```sql
ALTER TABLE tmp.table_description_test ALTER COLUMN a
SET OPTIONS (description = 'description of a');
```

```sql
ALTER TABLE tmp.table_description_test ALTER COLUMN b
SET OPTIONS (description = 'description of b');
```

But how can I add/change a description for the nested fields?

[image: KGk91y1]

```sql
ALTER TABLE tmp.table_description_test ALTER COLUMN b.c
SET OPTIONS (description = 'description of b.c');
```

Does not work:

```
Syntax error: Unexpected "." at [1:54]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding, we cannot use a BigQuery [alter](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#alter_column_set_options_statement)  DDL statement to modify nested columns. As a simple workaround you can consider using BigQuery UI to add description to the column.

**Example:**

[image]

If you want this feature to be implemented, you can open a new feature [request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) on the issue tracker. You can also take a look at the stack [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71776036/) also.

Comment: Thanks! Using the UI is not an option in my use case, because it's a few hundred tables, the description changes come in automatically from somewhere else, and the updates shall work without any manual clicking or typing. I'll go with a Java-API-based implementation.

Comment: And I've created this feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/308450971